# Aggregate function to Overlapping dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, overlap

I am trying to identify sum of quantity for each group if date ranges are overlapping. I am using postgresql to solve for it.
For example

| id | group | start_date | end_date | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2020-09-11 | 2020-10-09 | 50 |
| 1 | a | 2020-09-11 | 2020-10-31 | 20 |
| 1 | a | 2020-11-01 | 2020-12-01 | 7 |
| 1 | a | 2020-11-15 | 2020-11-20 | 6 |
| 2 | b | 2020-10-06 | 2020-10-30 | 10 |
| 2 | b | 2020-10-09 | 2022-10-17 | 5 |
| 2 | b | 2020-10-15 | 2022-10-26 | 3 |

What I am trying to achieve is the following: 
Expected Output: "edited"

| id | group | start_date | end_date | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2020-09-11 | 2020-10-31 | 70 |
| 1 | a | 2020-11-01 | 2020-12-01 | 13 |
| 2 | b | 2020-10-06 | 2020-10-30 | 18 |

would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION 1 : when all the date intervals within the same group are overlapping

```
SELECT id
     , group
     , min(start_date) AS start_date
     , max(end_date) AS end_date
     , Sum(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, group
```

SOLUTION 2 : when all the date intervals within the same group are not overlapping

Using a window function would be great but I don't see how to specify the window which corresponds to a subset of date ranges which overlap. So I come back to a basic solution based on a self-join which select for every row of table a the subset of rows of table b which overlap with that row :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id, date_start, date_end)
       a.id
     , min(b.start_date) AS date_start
     , max(b.end_date) AS date_end
     , sum(b.quantity) AS quantity
  FROM mytable AS a
 INNER JOIN mytable AS b
    ON a.id = b.id
   AND a.start_date < b.end_date
   AND a.end_date > b.start_date
 GROUP BY a.id, a.start_date, a.end_date
 ORDER BY a.id, date_start
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vEBCrl1d)

Comment: Appreciate it! But I don't think this would work if each group had different non-overlapping dates since I want to capture each date range if dates are not overlapping.

Comment: Ok please update pour question with an illustration of non overlapping dates for thé same group

Comment: Just did that. Thanks for your prompt reply!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `LAG` function to check the consecutive overlapped date periods and create unique groups for them as the following:

```
WITH create_groups AS
(
  SELECT *, SUM(chk) OVER (PARTITION BY id, group_ ORDER BY start_date) grp
  FROM
   (
     SELECT *,
        CASE 
         WHEN start_date <= LAG(end_date, 1, end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, group_ ORDER BY start_date) AND
              start_date >=LAG(start_date, 1, start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, group_ ORDER BY start_date) 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1
        END AS chk
     FROM table_name
  ) T
)
SELECT id, group_, 
       MIN(start_date) start_date,
       MAX(end_date) start_date,
       SUM(quantity) quantity
FROM create_groups
GROUP BY id, group_, grp
ORDER BY id, group_, grp
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zhPnma_s).